# XSLT script to remove elements after a particular element

Tags: xslt

I would like to transform the following XML

```
<item>
<uomConversion>
    <convRate>32</convRate>
    <disableDate/>                         
    <uomCodeFrom>EA</uomCodeFrom>    
    <uomCodeTo>CS</uomCodeTo>
</uomConversion>
<uomConversion>
    <convRate>864</convRate>
    <disableDate/>                         
    <uomCodeFrom>EA</uomCodeFrom>    
    <uomCodeTo>BX</uomCodeTo>
</uomConversion>
<uomConversion>
    <convRate>1762</convRate>
    <disableDate/>                         
    <uomCodeFrom>EA</uomCodeFrom>    
    <uomCodeTo>PLU</uomCodeTo>
</uomConversion>
<uomConversion>
    <convRate>1762</convRate>
    <disableDate/>                         
    <uomCodeFrom>EA</uomCodeFrom>    
    <uomCodeTo>PLS</uomCodeTo>
</uomConversion>
<uomConversion>
    <convRate>1762</convRate>
    <disableDate/>                         
    <uomCodeFrom>XYZ</uomCodeFrom>    
    <uomCodeTo>ABC</uomCodeTo>
</uomConversion>

</item>
```

by finding the first element that begins with PL, and removing all uomConversion elements that follow it. So for the example above the output would be:

```
<item>
<uomConversion>
    <convRate>32</convRate>
    <disableDate/>                         
    <uomCodeFrom>EA</uomCodeFrom>    
    <uomCodeTo>CS</uomCodeTo>
</uomConversion>
<uomConversion>
    <convRate>864</convRate>
    <disableDate/>                         
    <uomCodeFrom>EA</uomCodeFrom>    
    <uomCodeTo>BX</uomCodeTo>
</uomConversion>
<uomConversion>
    <convRate>1762</convRate>
    <disableDate/>                         
    <uomCodeFrom>EA</uomCodeFrom>    
    <uomCodeTo>PLU</uomCodeTo>
</uomConversion>
</item>
```

I have been trying withget this working, the solution that looked like it should work was the following, but it did not.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<!-- Identity template - copies all nodes and attributes as-is -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
 <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Find the position of the first uomConversion element that starts with PL -->
<xsl:variable name="positionToRemove">
 <xsl:number count="uomConversion[starts-with(uomCodeTo, 'PL')][1]" level="single"/>
</xsl:variable>

<!-- Match and remove uomConversion nodes after the first one starting with PL -->
<xsl:template match="uomConversion[position() > $positionToRemove]" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I don' t think you can use `xsl:number` like this, without a context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient solution here is probably sibling recursion:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <item>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="item/uomConversion[1]"/>
  </item>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="uomConversion">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  <xsl:if test="not(starts-with(uomCodeTo, 'PL'))">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::uomConversion[1]"/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

The draft XSLT 4.0 spec offers:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <item>
    <xsl:copy-of select="items-ending-with(item/uomConversion,
          fn{starts-with(uomCodeTo, 'PL')}"/>
  </item>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/item">
    <xsl:variable name="pl" select="uomConversion[starts-with(uomCodeTo, 'PL')][1]" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$pl | $pl/preceding-sibling::uomConversion"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <!-- Identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!-- Remove all uomConversion elements that are after the first uomConversion element that contains uomCodeTo=PL* -->
  <xsl:template match="uomConversion[preceding-sibling::uomConversion[starts-with(uomCodeTo,'PL')]]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqrbKT

Comment: It might work, but it's incredibly inefficient, especially if you only want the first 10 elements of a document containing thousands of elements.

Comment: I want all the elements, and there will only be 5 or 6 elements at most, so I think this will be ok.

Answer (score 1):

With XSLT 3, you could use an accumulator:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" use-accumulators="#all"/>
  
  <xsl:accumulator name="found" as="xs:boolean" initial-value="false()">
    <xsl:accumulator-rule match="uomConversion/uomCodeTo[starts-with(., 'PL')]" select="true()"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>
  
  <xsl:template match="uomConversion[accumulator-before('found')]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Might be less expensive than using the preceding sibling axis and could be used with streaming where preceding-sibling axis is not available:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" use-accumulators="#all" streamable="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:accumulator name="found" as="xs:boolean" initial-value="false()" streamable="yes">
    <xsl:accumulator-rule match="uomConversion/uomCodeTo/text()[starts-with(., 'PL')]" select="true()"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>
  
  <xsl:template match="uomConversion[accumulator-before('found')]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, these files are fairly small so I have gone with a simpler solution as none of us here are XWLT experts.